# Creating bootable CD/DVD :: need explanation about the boot information (*.bif) files

Tags: windows-7, boot, dvd, bootable-media

Trying to install the GPARTED tool as a bootable DVD with powerISO. 
The instruction points out that I should verify that the disk is bootable - it's not.
I should add the boot information (*bif) file.

1. What is a boot information?
2. But where should I get it? -> I know I can extract it, but will any type work?
3. What kind do I need? Anykind will do? Would it work if I just downloaded and added one of these: http://www.allbootdisks.com/download/iso.html or here: http://www.winiso.com/support/tutorials/make-windows7-bootable.html (2 links to the windows 7 boot information files).

As you probably suspect I would not like to ruine my DVD's one by one trying different combinations - so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://gparted.org/livecd.php for information on creating a bootable DVD (or CD, the ISO file should easily fit). You might prefer to make a bootable USB flash drive, which can be reused if it does not work the first time.

The biggest issue in making newer computers using UEFI boot from alternate media is allowing legacy, non-UEFI, bootup in BIOS (UEFI); see instruction for your particular PC in setting up BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Waiting for the answer I actually burned 1 CD with windows 7 boot information file and it does not work - is it because the GPARTED runs in a debian environment (when booted through the CD)?

Comment: That makes sense -- when running from your bootable media, rather than the HDD, you're PC is operating in that OS (Debian, in this case), so you'd need a Debian boot sector. BTW, you might try Ubuntu Live CD with gparted, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted.